# LinkedIn V2 api: Not enough permissions to access /me GET

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been trying to use the linkedin V2 api, but constantly getting error. 
I created an developer application. Set up redirect url as "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback" to make request using postman (as per postman documentation). 
Filled up form to request access token.

[image]

But everytime I use the token and make a query, I get an error:

[image]

But I have selected all the default application permissions in my application. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LinkedIn API has been [largely closed off](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) and is only available to approved LinkedIn developers. You can request authorisation here: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Comment: I just want to implement sign up. Do I still have to apply there.

Comment: `r_basicprofile` should theoretically be accessible without requesting this formal authorization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context However, many fields are not working for me even after getting`r_basicprofile` granted by the user.

Comment: @Sinister Beard, there isn't any reason to request this authorisation if we only need do use OAuth2 basic profile - in my case, only email address. There isn't anything in LinkedIn user guide for developers that suggest to do this.

Comment: @mpoletto No, there isn't - but that's the documentation being lacking.

Comment: @SinisterBeard How can you sure about that?

Comment: I mean, I can't prove a negative, but can you make it work?

Comment: @SinisterBeard No, I can't. And I tried to request an authorisation to become a marketing partner and they denied. Now, I understand there isn't any information in official documentation about the new politic to approve new developers users for their API.

Comment: @mpoletto https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes - I'll add this to my answer as well.

Comment: Does anybody know what permission is needed to access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/contacts-api ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a old question, but the solution is to use the scope **r_liteProfile** instead of r_basicprofile during the first step of authorization.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=*****&redirect_uri=http://yourauthorizationserver&state=RandomString&scope=r_liteprofile
```

Then, use the value of the code parameter passed back from LinkedIn to http://yourauthorizationserver in the second step of authorization:

```
curl -X POST \
'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?code=codeobtainedwiththefirstcall&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=*****&client_id=***&redirect_uri=yourredirecturi' \
```

Solution found here:
[Any queries to the api.linkedin.com/v2/ return "Not enough permissions to access ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960458/any-queries-to-the-api-linkedin-com-v2-return-not-enough-permissions-to-access?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What permission is needed to access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/contacts-api ?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked and allowed access to "r_basicprofile" permissions? go to your app and check your Default Application Permissions for people/~/me endpoint.

Comment: Even with that permission, it does not appear to work. LinkedIn is completely closed now. We should all stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct url for the user info call is: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo
Linkedin doc is not updated as well but this one will for sure work for you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDHRV.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35500940)

Comment: Understandable i am kinda new here ,
So the reason why this url works for the endpoint is because the new linkedin docs have permissions changed from the original ones  that were being used like r_basicprofile 
The new permissions look like this "profile" 
And hence the api endpoint has also  changed i was able to find this endpoint from the internet and this seems to be working

Answer (score -1):

If you are using https://oauth.io/ you have to add scopes in the ***Keys and Permission Scope*** configuration page:

[image]