# Linkedin Developer Company Search API

Tags: linkedin-api

I created an app in LinkedIn Developer account. I currently have access to the following scopes: r_emailaddress and r_liteprofile. How can I get access to the Company Search API? I generated an access token already, and tried to access the "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companySearch?q=search" API endpoint, but I got this error message back: "Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /companySearch". How can I get permissions for this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943710/19330634) help you ? Seems like a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Look through this page and see if a permission matches up with what you're trying to accomplish. I'm guessing that you need to apply for marketing or sales permissions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-07